# JDialogs cause my application's menus to disappear on OSX

Tags: java, swing, macos, jdialog

Whenever any of my JDialogs have focus the toolbar does not display any menus accept for my applications main menu (it doesn't show file edit etc....).  Is this an issue inherent to JDialogs/Swing or is this some sort of problem with how I made my dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing can optionally use the `JMenuBar` from your application's `JFrame` and display it along the top of the screen. Set the following property to enable that feature.

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
```

Unfortunately, this [does not work with `JDialog`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html), only `JFrame`.